# How can I make a telegram bot wait for a response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I write a telegram bot that checks the dictionary key with the entered message , and if the message matches/does not matches the dictionary value , the bot outputs the message "true"/"not true", and proceeds to the next key. But when I go through the dictionary with the **for in** loop, the bot does not expect a response, but displays all the keys in the dictionary at once.

How can I make the bot wait for a message for each of the keys in dictionary?

**My code:**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])

def newfunc(message):
    for key in dict.keys():
        bot.reply_to(message, key)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, func)

def func(message):
    rightanswer = 0
    wronganswer = 0

    for value in dict.values():
        if (message.text == value):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Yes')
            rightanswer += 1
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'No')
            wronganswer += 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Right answers: {} Wrong answers: {}'.format(rightanswer, wronganswer))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: Can you give an example of input/output you expect of your bot? Something like:

User: blahblahblah
Bot: response1, response2
User blahblah
Bot: response1.

That way it's going to be easier to understand what do you want to do and to help you.

Answer (score 0):

did not understand your question

you can fully control how the bot works;

all you need is to set up the Telegram Bot and write the function to perform the desired action;

read this:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests

Telegram Bot API

```
The Bot API is an HTTP-based interface created for developers keen on building bots for Telegram.
To learn how to create and set up a bot, please consult our Introduction to Bots and Bot FAQ.
```

Have a Web App with the following method

```
function doPost(e) {
```

to listen for incoming requests via the Bot
you can write your code to perform the desired action

hope this helps

cheers